# how to use data returned by php in chrome packaged app

Tags: php, google-chrome, iot, google-chrome-app

I am finishing my large app which uses Vue.js on client side, and php and mysql on server side, however both client and server side will run on the same computer which won't have access to internet. Any security issues like XSS attacks and so on are not a problem right now.

Because app also need access to IoT i decided to use google chrome apps so i can create tcp server and exchange data via TCP protocol with arduino. I did sth like this before, and it is not an issue. However need of using mysql and php face me today with a huge problem - how to use google chrome packaged app with php files.

First attempt was to just load a php file in bacgkround.js file like this:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('admin/admin.php', {
    'outerBounds': {
      'width': 400,
      'height': 500
    }
  });
});
```

It didnt work - whole php code of file was treated as pure text (not compiled).

Later i decided to create a file admin.html and change above code to admin/admin.html which holds:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello, let's code!</h1>
</body>
</html>
  <script src='../libraries/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='test.js'></script>
```

and test.js looks like this:

```
console.log('Did it load?')
$.ajax({
    url: '../server/admin.php'
}).done(function (data) {
$('body').html(data)
})
```

I loaded jQuery just to speed up my tests.
Unfortunatelly it still doesnt work. Code of admin.php is loaded correctly, but only html tags. PHP is commented automatically by the browser. Also vue library is ignored, but I didnt went there yet.

The question is: 
- how to use php generated by apache files in google chrome packaged apps
if it is not possible:
- is that possible to create tcp server within google packaged app, and let it communicate with normal page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: A browser does not interpret or execute PHP code. You need to have a web server that does this for you. In the context of your app, calling `../server/admin.php` is just pulling the raw PHP code, and there's nothing to interpret it.

Comment: I of course - which i didnt mention but i thought it is quite obvious - i have running xampp so i do have an apache web server. It works all fine but packed apps ignore web server. I also am aware the difference between server and client side programming, and js, may use compiled files of php - that's why i used ajax call

Comment: You need to use a full URL like `http://localhost/path/endpoint.php`.